# Is Co-browsing feature possible with WEBRTC?

Tags: javascript, java, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I have simple question.

Is Co-browsing feature possible with WEBRTC?

If yes then how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its possible, both things are from different tech stack and have no conflict with each other. So we can implement co-browse with WebRTC easily.

As for webrtc you must be using signaling from server side, i'd suggest to use that same for cobrowsing or optionally you can use `RTCDataChannel` layer for data exchange.

I am working at [Tagove](http://www.tagove.com) where we have cobrowse along with WebRTC and that really works great.

**Problems we faced**

In our tagove solution whenever we change page in cobrowsing, webrtc stack also get reloaded, but nobody want that glitch, so we implemented a magical solution to fix it up. We use cobrowsing in iframe to manage this and then without a second of call disconnect customer can browse whole website while still on call on same page with video/voice call.

If you would like to see demo you can start a chat and co-browse with us at http://www.tagove.com/co-browsing-software

[DISCLAIMER: I do work at tagove as CTO]

Answer (score 2):

Co-browsing is not integrated out-of-the-box in WebRTC. You can do screen sharing.

Co-browsing you must implement it yourself, but you can `RTCDataChannel` as the communication channel. Though RTCDataChannels is not something specific for this purpose, is just a way to send data between two peers on top of which you can implement the entire co-browsing feature. You can check this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/

On the other hand, if you implement it using these, your application will become dependent on WebRTC and you'll need anyway a signaling mechanism. Taking these into consideration it might be a better idea to use websockets, with even better support on browsers.

Comment: Do you have any example for this? How can we use RTCDataChannel for this purpose?

Comment: Ok. I will first go with normal websocket

Comment: Cool, don't forget to accept and vote the answer :).